# Где выгоднее хранить данные об онлайн статусе серверов

Tags: php, mysql, json, mariadb, хранение-данных

Есть много автоматов по продаже чего-либо, у каждого автомата есть онлайн статус (работа/сбой/перезагрузка и др). Есть панель управления, куда вся эта информация должна приходить, чтобы ее можно было смотреть в режиме реального времени, то есть статусы могут довольно часто изменяться. Вопрос - как грамотно реализовать запись/хранение/чтение этих статусов? Есть предположения БД или JSON файлик. Серверная часть будет написана на PHP. Буду рад помощи!

Comment: Любая in-memory БД, например?

Comment: С моими начальными знаниями в php, освоение  in-memory немного сложновато по причине нехватки времени, а так учту на будущее. Что скажете насчет записи статусов в json?

Comment: Если вам надо хранить данные и у вас есть база данных, то для чего вам какие-то то файлики?

Comment: Я посчитал, что частое изменение записей в БД к хорошему не приведет. В плане, что отдельный json файлик, в котором есть номер каждого сервера и его онлайн статус, который можно считывать и выводить в ПУ. Я неверно мыслю?

Comment: Если некий создаваемый Вами агент мониторит статус или создаваемый Вами софт автомата его шлёт - пусть сразу пишет в БД. А вот если автомат шлёт свой статус неуправляемым внутренним ПО... то зависит от того, как именно он это делает. *Я неверно мыслю?* Увы...

Comment: В теории, если автомат меняет свой статус, то он будет извещать об этом сервер. Также, возможно, чтобы главный сервер иногда тоже опрашивал автоматы, и если какой-нибудь из автоматов молчит - выводится статус "Не доступен". То есть здесь будет двухстороннее общение автоматов и сервера. Поэтому меня здесь почему-то тянет к отдельному json файлику, но я не уверен в правильности данного выбора.

Comment: Zend_Log, это то, что нужно!) Спасибо огромное!